# Google analytics V3 page views result for website is significantly deviating from sum of dimension wise page views for same website

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I have built a set up in my java project for Google Analytics API v3 and it's returning data feeds for different dimensions and profile id(websites). Following are the inputs which I am providing in query to hit the API -

```
metrics - ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:timeOnPage,ga:avgTimeOnPage
dimensions - ga:date,ga:country
ids - ga:77477074 (dummy)
start/end date - 2015-03-02
feedUrl - https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data
filter - ga:hostname!~^m.
service account id-9334872717895hjo2gj7jucrh5ncjclkp2qnpdck7jdj@developer.gserviceaccount.com(dummy)
Secret Key - MyProject-fc80391408ca.p12(dummy)
Analytics dependency -
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-analytics</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev127-1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I hit the API to get Page Views for date 2015-03-02 and got the Page Views count - `17087720`

Then I added one more dimension 'ga:country' in the query and got the country wise Page Views for same date and same profile id. Sum of all Page Views for different countries is - `11289093`

I wonder why it is significantly less than `17087720`. Ideally both results should be close enough rather deviating by roughly 29% as I only added a dimension 'Country' but the profile id is still same.

Can somebody hint me what is wrong ? Is Google returning incorrect sampled data ?

Comment: If some of the data you are requesting doesn't have country information then then those rows wont be returned.    This would depend on the types of hits and how you are sending data to Google Analytics.  Check the response from the server it will tell you though if its sampled.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion looks quite reasonable but i doubt the result because the deviation margin is high. It's roughly 5 lac (29%). And i checked the server response also, it doesn't tell that data is sampled. One more thing i would ask that is API v3 efficient enough to rely upon for reporting purpose in live projects ? Any algorithm improvement from Google side in case of fault in v3.!!

Comment: We use it for a mission critical application at the company I work for yes the data is efficient enough to rely upon.    You just have to understand that this is a multidimensional database and not a relational database the data that is returned is not the same.

Comment: I thank you for your kind replies. :) As per my requirement, i need data feeds with date, country & state dimensions but i'm worrying about the data inconsistency as it's deviating hugely(by 25-30%). I got your point that i'm retrieving data from multidimensional DB but not from the relational DB, so the data lags will always be there. Can you please suggest me some other tricks or any possible method to optimize the result in order to make it more useful for the business, if any !! I'll be grateful to you. Thanks..

Comment: I would start by checking out the ISO dimensions they are better then using the string ones there can be more then one city in the world with the same name.   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=geo_network    And don't request data that is under 48 hours old its not done processing and wont be accurate.   and compare your data directly in the web application.  The numbers should match.   The data is correct its getting the data out correctly that is the trick.

Comment: @DalmTo, I would be grateful to you if you suggest me how to get the list of Countries in GA library. Similarly another list containing Countries and corresponding States and third list containing Countries and their corresponding States and Cities. My requirement is to populate them in my application to prepare different combinations of matrices as an input filter. Thank You.!

Comment: GA is not a library its an API.  I would check out https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=geo_network you will need to make requests to populate it with new data all the time though.  A better option would be to find a list on the internet some place and use that

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have actually found the list of Countries from here - https://deconf.com/country-codes-for-google-analytics-dashboard/ as you are suggesting it's better option. But it's being difficult to find the corresponding States & Cities. !!

Comment: Google Analytics dashboard is not Google analytics its a third party Google analytics plugin.  I am afraid I cant help with that I don't support third party products you may want to contact the developer of that plugin.

Comment: Ok.. I found one more list of countries here. http://www.codingwithcody.com/2011/05/google-analytics-country-names/ Can i rely on it ? I'm still unable to find corresponding States and Cities.